# How to get associated data with from a model in django?

Tags: django, templates, view, model

I am trying to return the associated reviews once a user clicks on the given productname.  The view I am using is:

```
def index(request):
    prod_list = Website.objects.values('productname').distinct()
    return render_to_response('reserve/templates/index.html', {'prod_list': prod_list})
```

The template I have is:

```
 {% for website in prod_list %}
        <a href="/clubs/{{ website.id }}/detail">{{ website.productname }}</a>
        <br>{{  website.review }} <br><br>
    {% endfor %}
```

The model I am using is:

```
class Website(models.Model):
    productname = models.CharField('Website name', max_length = 100)
    review = models.CharField('Review', max_length = 200)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.productname
```

There are multiple reviews for each productname listed; the problem I am running into is that the link (  ) is not returning a website.id.  Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model structure is not really suitable. What you really need are separate tables for Reviews and Products, then a `ForeignKey` from Review to Product so that they are in a one-to-many relationship. Then you can easily get each distinct product, and iterate through the reviews for each one.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values)

> values
>
> values(*fields)
>
> Returns a ValuesQuerySet — a QuerySet subclass that returns
> dictionaries when used as an iterable, rather than model-instance
> objects.

So what you are actually iterating over are dictionary objects.

Secondly, when you restrict the values fields, only those fields are returned. `prod_list` actually is:

`[{'productname': u'Product Name 1'},{'productname': u'Product Name 2'}, ...]`

Updating your view to this `prod_list = Website.objects.distinct('productname')` will make your template render correctly as it will return a queryset.

#### Edit

Since `DISTINCT ON` is only supported for postgresql, you can use this work around:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# ... your other imports

def index(request):

    prod_list_distinct = set()
    for obj in Website.objects.all():
       prod_list_distinct.add(obj.productname) # sets only allow uniques

    prod_list = Website.objects.filter(productname__in=prod_list_distinct)

    return render(request,
                  'reserve/templates/index.html', {'prod_list': prod_list})
```

Comment: I am getting an error "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend" when I use this definition for prod_list.

Comment: Ah yes, this is only supported on Postgres. I have updated my answer with a different approach.